# SignalR unavailable reasons

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm developing a real time application using SignalR. Where SigalR will be hosted in an ASP.NET (VB.NET v.2010)

I have the following questions regarding SignalR availability:

1. What are the cases on which a client could not connect to the signalR?
2. Is SignalR is trusted to support Real Time Applications?
3. To have a static (shared) array in the hub, will it affect the performance if the array is too big?
4. Since the user of the client app will connect to the ASP.NET app via web-service, then is there a cases where the client app can consume the web-service and can not connect to the SignalR?
5. Can SignalR keep alive for long time, since my app will be working 24/7?´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the cases on which a client could not connect to the signalR?

Network failure will do it. SignalR will attempt to reconnect due to a transient failure. Or your app being down. :-)

> Is SignalR is trusted to support Real Time Applications?

Yep. I'm currently working on an app that has around 3K continuously active users and we never have any widespread connectivity problems. In fact, I don't even recall seeing a support ticket related to SignalR connectivity.

> To have a static (shared) array in the hub, will it affect the performance if the array is too big?

Well, pursuant to available memory, you should be fine. Be careful with threading. If you are locking to access an array that is frequently updated, watch out for lock contention.

> Since the user of the client app will connect to the ASP.NET app via web-service, then is there a cases where the client app can consume the web-service and can not connect to the SignalR?

I can't envision a scenario. A proper SignalR implementation would be available if network connectivity is available.

> Can SignalR keep alive for long time, since my app will be working
>   24/7?

Yep. SignalR will attempt to reconnect due to transient network interruptions. You can also handle events on the client for disconnect to attempt to reconnect after SignalR gives up.